# execute script on shortcut key in all runlevels

Tags: debian, keyboard-shortcuts, brightness

I have a laptop with intel graphics. The `Fn` key brightness control only works when the user is logged into the desktop environment. It never works in the login screen or in tty sessions. I have to manually execute command as root to change brightness in tty sessions which is kinda pain, considering brightness wont persist on reboot.

I can change brightness by writing value to `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` which requires root permissions. I have a bash script that increases or decreases brightness by 10percent based on argument it receives.

Now I want to change brightness whenever I press some key combination by executing this script in all runlevels. How can I do that, in both init and systemd systems? I need the solution irrelevant to the Desktop Environment. I use debian wheezy.

Say,

```
LCtrl + LShift + LArrow --> decrease brightness.
LCtrl + LShift + RArrow --> increase brightness.
```